# Using Hardware acceleration in different fragments

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration, glsurfaceview, textureview, android-hardware

I use single activity approach in my app and I have 2 fragments. In first fagment I have GLSurfaceView and it dosen't work correctly, when hardwareAccelerated="false". In second fragment I have TextureView and TextureView or a subclass can only be used with hardware acceleration enabled. So when hardwareAccelerated="false" first fragment with GLSurfaceView dosen't work, and when hardwareAccelerated="true" second fragment with TextureView dosen't work. How can I fix this?

I tryed set  in AndroidManifest and then change it to true for textureView only using setLayerType in onViewCreated fun in SecondFragment, but I still have error: TextureView or a subclass can only be used with hardware acceleration enabled.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding.textureView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
```

I also tryed setFlags in MainActivity when I move from one fragment to another. Still same error

```
window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
)
```

Comment: This may be a case where you are better served by having different activities host the fragments. However, AFAIK `TextureView` should work fine with hardware acceleration enabled, so you might want to look more into why you are encountering problems there.

Comment: The hardware acceleration flag is relevant when you draw on the view's canvas. But the content of `GLSurfaceView` is drawn using OpenGL. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @dev.bmax I have app with AR functionality and I'm using EasyAR lib for ar and GLSurfaceView for camera preview. When android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in my app it works correctly, but when I switch it to true, I have screen with "white noise" and this errors:

Comment: eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
eglQueryContext(2122): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x500
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glEnable:4892
GL error 0x500 condition
[!GLESv2Validation::allowedEnable(ctx->majorVersion(), ctx->minorVersion(), what)]

Comment: Are you sure you need a `GLSurfaceView` for a camera preview? Because usually people use a `SurfaceView` or `TextureView`?

Comment: Also what makes you think that you need to have `hardwareAccelerated="true"`?

Comment: Well, I have TextureView in other fragment and TextureView can only be used with hardware acceleration enabled